# import large sql dump into Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of sql files which I could successfully import into my local mysql server. but one of them is the largest around 7 gigs and when I try to import it to mysql it just takes forever with no errors. I don't know how to find what's wrong..

I use `mysql -u root --max_allowed_packet=8G < data.sql`

I get however the `warning option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 6G adjusted to 2147483648.`

Any thoughts on what could be up with this system is very appreciated.

Comment: how long is forever? depending on your server machine and sql server config, it could take anywhere between half hour and a day. If there's no error, maybe just give it time. You mentioned LOCAL MYSQL SERVER, so I am guessing it's not a dedicated machine with serious HD/ram, in which case, would not expect it to happen under 1h

Comment: for a 3g file it takes 10 minutes. for this file it takes more than an hour with no success..

Answer (score 1):

sql file can be split in crumb ,
I google  and found ,
This my be your solution http://www.sqldumpsplitter.com/  ,
neither  I tested nor used , Please test with example file before use

Hope it is helpful !